# Server 2012 RAID 1 drive expansion onto additional RAID 1 disk

Tags: raid, windows-server-2012, raid-1

I currently have two 500GB HDD set up as RAID 1 on server 2012 via the C100 raid controller. This is disk 0. They are split into C: and D: drives/volumes

- `C:` has the OS and program files,
- `D:` has some data.

The D: drive is almost full, so I put in two Seagate 2TB HDD and configured them in RAID 1. This is Disk 1.

What I am trying to achieve is to extend the D: partition onto Disk1 for more storage.
I’ve tried to convert Disk 0 to dynamic but I get

> The selected GPT formatted disk contains a partition which is not of type 'PARTITION_BASIC_DATA_GUID' and is both preceeded and followed by a partition of type 'PARTITION_BASIC_DATA_GUID'

Can anyone advise?
Do I need to move D: over to Disk1 entirely? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You will be limited by the capacity of the smaller (500GB) drives, so a spanned volume would not be an option in this case.

You could either:

- Create a 2TB volume on Disk1 and copy/move the data from D: to there. This option will let you dedicate the full size of that volume to the data.

or

- Swap one of the 500GB drives with a 2TB drive. Let the array rebuild, swap the remaining drive, rebuild, then expand the capacity of the virtual disk followed by an expansion of the D: volume. With this option you will share the capacity with the C: volume.